# MYSQL, PHP, PDO Check if row exists

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to check to see if value stored in $steamId is already in the table but its not working. What am i doing wrong.

Account_info table

```
+------------+---------+----------+-----+
| Steam_id   | Partner | Token    | RID |
+------------+---------+----------+-----+
| Steamid222 | Part222 | token222 |   1 |
+------------+---------+----------+-----+

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Steam_id from Account_info WHERE Steam_id = ':id'");
$stmt->bindParam(":id", '$steamId');
$stmt->execute();    

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
//user exists
}
else
{
//user doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: Wrong quotes. `'$steamId'` Should be double quotes `"$steamId"`... or no quotes. Single quotes make it literal. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: and............ `':id'` remove those too for `Steam_id = ':id'`. you're treating it as a string literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the exact string `'$steamId'` to the id so that it will search for an user with the id of `'$steamId'`.

```
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $steamId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Also you can remove the quotes from the select statement.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Steam_id from Account_info WHERE Steam_id = :id");
```

Comment: Thank you. I also just realized my table is acutally called Account_Info so there was another mistake lol.